# javascript - Post large DATA with xmlhttpRequest

Tags: javascript

I need to post DATA from client to server every 5 second by setInterval.
But the DATA is not sent every 5 second.
Here is my function.
How to faster post the DATA?

```
function sendData(url, DATA){
    xmlhttpRequest ({
        method:     "POST",
        url:        url,
        data:       JSON.stringify(DATA),
        onload:     function (data) {
            console.log(data.response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not use a websocket?

Comment: `But the DATA is not sent every 5 second` how often is it sent? How long does it take to send? if it takes longer than 5 seconds to send, then you simply can not expect to send it every 5 seconds

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` you are more than likely going to end up having multiple requests going at the same time if the data is large enough. Which will further slow down the request(s) which will then make it so more requests are sent at the same time, etc etc etc

Comment: Note that setInterval does not guarantee to call the callback function exactly in the specified interval. Also `JSON.stringify` is synchronous and blocks the event loop; you might want to consider using workers if DATA is large